# Which case has more performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have about 10 k user nodes on my graph database. I know its not too much but i am searching for the best solution for my case.

I need to mark some of my users and query for them later.

I came up with two solutions (at least for now) but I could not decide which one is best for performance, what do you think about my possible solutions?

1 - I can **Add** new property **to all my user nodes** with default value of false.

```
MATCH (u:User) SET u.marked = false
```

After that i will set marked property to true for all users that i need to query later. Lets say there are 50 of them.

Later when i need those marked users i will query like:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.marked = true RETURN u
```

2 - I can **add** new property **only to those users that i will need later** and does not modify other user nodes. Like the following:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id IN [...,123,456,789,...] SET u.marked = true
```

Later when i need marked users, i will query like:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.marked = true RETURN u
```

or

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE EXISTS(u.marked) AND u.marked = true RETURN u
```

If you know another way that solves my problem, i am open for opinions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could store marked users id's in separate table. And when you need to mark them again, you just clear previous results and save new ones. Later on if needed, you could easily add other properties.

Comment: use `PROFILE` before query you will get details of it.
like `PROFILE MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.marked = true RETURN u`

Comment: Just so you know, in second option in the description, the match where u.marked = true is enough. An existence check isn't needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach would be to create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(marked);
```

Then, your queries will be able to quickly get the marked `User` nodes without having to scan all of them.

@InverseFalcon's answer presents another possible approach, the creation of a label.

Comment: This one seems best fit to my case, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean fields should work fine. Usman Maqbool's advice for profiling the different ways is good...do that to find what works best for you.

Another way is to create a label specifically for this, :MarkedUser, for example. Remember that nodes can have multiple labels without problems.

You can set the label on your interested set of users using (for users u) `SET u:MarkedUser`.

Lookup becomes easy, because it's all users in that label. Just match, do your processing, then remove the label. If you can do this all in one query, it would look like:

```
MATCH (u:MarkedUser)
// do your processing here
REMOVE u:MarkedUser
```